# Utilisation du présent à la place du futur après « dès que »

Tags: temps-grammatical

Lu aujourd'hui dans la presse française :

> Dès que ces lunettes sont mises sur le marché, nous sommes prêts.

**Le contexte :** un éditeur de logiciel annonçant qu'il commençait à développer des applications pour les lunettes interactives [GoogleGlass](http://www.google.com/glass/start/) bien qu'elles ne soient pas encore commercialisées.

La phrase m'a tout de suite piqué les yeux. À chaud je remplacerais les deux formes *sont* / *sommes* du verbe *être* par leur équivalent futur *seront* / *serons*, mais en fait la phrase ne sonne pas mieux pour autant.

Donc ma question : **est-ce que la phrase d'origine est correcte ?**

Et sinon quelle serait la (les) bonne(s) tournure(s) ?

Comment: C'est en effet une tournure un peu bancale, mais on peut comprendre que la seule chose qui manque pour que nous soyons prêts est que ces lunettes sortent à la vente. Si elles devaient être mises en vente à l'instant, nous serions prêts. Pour retranscrire cet effet d'imminence, le présent n'est pas mal choisi. Ajouter un lien vers l'article, ou ajouter un peu de contexte, aiderait à apporter une réponse définitive.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon ajout d'un peu de contexte. Et effectivement ta proposition imparfait/conditionnel sonne bien, bien qu'elle change la phrase.

Answer (score 2):

> Dès que ces lunettes sont mises sur le marché, nous sommes prêts.

je suis du même avis qu'Alexis, je pense que le présent est utilisé ici comme forme *journalistique*, pour mettre en évidence que le produit sera incessament sur le marché… Ou du moins que l'auteur de la phrase y croit fortement.

J'aurais peut-être préféré une autre formulation de cette même phrase:

> Nous sommes prêts, et ce, dès que ces lunettes sont mises sur le marché.